# Specifying multiple columns of Quandl data to download with column_index

Tags: multiple-columns, quandl

With Google Financial, you can specify which columns of data you want to download. Can that be done with Quandl data? If so, I can't find an example that illustrates how.

I want to download Open and Close data only, not the entire table which is quite large. Quandl does supply a URL parameter, `column_index` that allows specification of a single column, so I can query for Close data only, or Open data only, but not both.

Perhaps, this can't be done. Could someone please confirm?